# Sass 3.2 Prerelease with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I would like to use the new SASS 3.2 with rails (3.2).
It seems that sass-rails depends on sass 3.1

How might I go about crafting the Gemfile to use the pre-release 
SASS 3.2 gem?

I have tried to fork the sass-rails project and upgrade the sass dependency myself but with no luck and only errors when trying to run bundler..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the version as a second arg in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sass', '3.2.0.alpha.237'
```

and it will install the version that you have set.

Comment: Yeah, you can also use the `~>` to get all prerelease updates (i.e. `~> 3.2.beta`)